# Show and hide column in a table using drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a table, which looks exactly like this one: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

I now want to replace the headers (*the th things*) with a drop down. I want to hide and show columns thanks to those drop downs (they can click and show what they want).

I was also wondering if I can leave some columns by default.
Is all of that possible ?

Comment: Hi Manon, You'll probably have to add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. (There's a bit of a formula to asking on Stack) You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you hide a column from a drop down, how would you propose to then show the column from a hidden drop down?

Comment: @ManonKalfon What version of data tables are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but have you started developing anything? Do you have any code for us to work with? I can point you at a couple good sources to get you started if not.

First off, here is how to add a select menu to a column:

```
<th>Date
    <select id="filter_dt" class="headerFilter">
        <option value="show">Show</option>
        <option value="hide">Hide</option>
    </select>
</th>
```

The above code will provide a drop down for columns.

You could show/hide columns by doing the following (from [DOCs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)):

```
$('.headerFilter').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible(! column.visible());
});
```

As far as a default column, it depends on how you're rendering the data in the table, but you should be able to accomplish this by simply doing the following (Directly from the [DOCs](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/bubble-editing/inTableControls.html)):

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    columns: [
        { data: "first_name" },
        { data: "last_name" },
        { data: "position" },
        { data: "office" },
        { data: "start_date" },
        { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) },
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a>',
            orderable: false
        },
    ]
});
```

The last column specified in the `<a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a>` value.

Comment: I already managed to do the "hide and show" but you have the names written and then you click on it to make it desapear, I want the same thing to work with a drop down, and it that possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible: [Column Visibility](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/)